# How to properly implement a static cell with Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uitableview

I literally could not find a single tutorial that showed me how to build an app that uses static cells; with clickable cells. Based on few out dated posted and object-c answers, I've put something together. My issue is, when I click on a cell, I get `staticDemoTableCell` is has no member `present`.

I have embedded a Table Controller in my UIViewController. For that cell (only one so far), I've created a class:

```
class staticDemoTableCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    [...]
    tableView.delegate = self
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("clicked") // Works when the cell is clicked
    // self.present() do not work. I need to present another viewcontroller when this cell is clicked
  }

}
```

Something does not sit right, **for every cell is a class?**

I really need to know if I went the correct way about doing this. What I really want is more to this such. Have you seen ie: grouped transactions Monday: a list, Tuesday: a list etc. Each cell will be clickable just like the settings of your iOS device. Any pointers will be highly grateful.

Comment: The cell generally isn't the `UITableViewDelegate` (because you have multiple cells, but the table view can have only one delegate). Generally the view controller would be (and only would be if you set the `delegate` of the table view accordingly).

Comment: @Rob Thanks for that.

Comment: "Something does not sit right, for every cell is a class?" if it wasn't clear from the answer below (and my comment, above), no, you don't need (nor want, most likely) different classes for the cells. In fact you don't need a `UITableViewCell` subclass at all. It's really powerful for dynamic cells, but for static table it's entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @Rob Think about the Settings section (app) of your iOS device, is not that static cells? When you click on a cell, you get different VCs. Excuse my questions, I've just started learning and finding it difficult to find tutorials before asking such questions.

Comment: It could be static or dynamic cells. But that's not my point. I'm just saying that if you're doing static cells, `UITableViewCell` subclasses are far less useful. These subclasses are useful for providing an elegant way to programmatically referencing custom controls in cells, but offers little utility in static cells where you can just as easily use simple outlets in the view controller.

Comment: Regarding how you transition from tapping on static cell to the next scene, if every cell takes you to different scene, then its easier to use segues right in IB from the cells to the various different scenes. You get your UI with less programming. But if you have a dozen static cells can take you to the same "next scene", then rather than having a dozen segues from different cells to the same next scene, I'd instead have a single segue to that next scene, and then have the `didSelect` programmatically perform that single segue for all of the relevant custom cells.

Comment: @Rob Excellent! Much appreciated for your time and comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's much easier if the table view contains **only** static cells:

- In Interface Builder select the table view and set the `Content` to `Static Cells`
- Create `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s in the controller class and connect them.
- Implementing table view data source methods and subclassing cells is not needed.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have set to static and grouped. `IBOutlets` are connected but I do not have any `IBAction`; no buttons. A cell should be clickable that takes me to x view controller. How?

Comment: I've never tried it myself but doesn't the delegate `didSelect...` (implemented in the controller) work?

Comment: Yes that works. I got the print. The aim is to navigate to another view controller. `self.present` do not work. I assume `present` works only in a uiviewcontroller? I know something is wrong here.

Comment: You can use performSegue(withIdentifier...) if you have a segue from the view containing the table view to the other view controller

Comment: @Sylar - Yes, you can use `didSelect` and that's probably good approach if multiple cells transition to the same destination. Clearly, though, you want to supply a parameter to `present`, in order to specify to what you are transitioning (e.g. `storyboard.instantiateViewController(...)`). Or create a single segue between the view controllers and then programmatically perform that segue.

Comment: I was reading that few people had the same issue. I'll try that out later when I get back. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vadian, your answer worked but the use of static cells is not clear.

Comment: Static cells are used like other UI elements (labels, buttons etc.). There are no datasource methods `cellForRow...` and `numberOfRows...`.

Comment: Xcode doesn't seem to allow the creation of actions from a `UITableViewCell`; just outlets / outlet collections. Is there an extra step needed here to make an `IBAction` connected to a cell?

Comment: @TheNeil Of course you can create actions in a table view cell but in case of static cells create them in the controller.

Answer (score 9):

So you can do the following. Set your table view, then make the cells static, once you've done that, you need to make sure you know how many sections you are going to have. This depends on your design or what you want to achieve.

Then you can do something like this:

If you have more than one section, and section 1 has more than one cell. And section 2 has only one cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            // Do something
        case 1:
            // Do something 
        default:
            break
        }
    case 2:
        // Do something
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

If you have only one section with two cells you can do something like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        // Do something
    case 1:
        // Do something
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For the rows in the different sections you can do the following by example for 3 sections. Section 1 has 1 row, section 2 has 6 and section 3 has 3 rows:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 1
    case 1:
        return 6
    case 2:
        return 3
    default:
        return 0
    }
    
}
```